# Mapbox gl : How to perform a filter in a polygon?

Tags: filter, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I want to make a filter on the geometry of my layer source vector.

```
var polygone = .....
var filter = polygone.reduce(function (memo, coord) {
    memo.push(coord);
    return memo;
}, ['in', '$coordinates']);
map.setFilter(layer, filter);
```

But I can not figure out how to apply the filter. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Diallo! According to the [filter help page](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#types-filter), you could use `map.setFilter(layer, ["has", key])`.